# Add comma to numbers every three digits in datatable (R)

Tags: r, format, number-formatting, dt

Suppose my data looks like this:

```
df1 = data.frame(A=c(1000000.51,5000.33), B=c(0.565,0.794))
```

I want to use [DataTables](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/)  and have column A be (1,000,001 ; 5,000)

```
library(DT)
datatable(df1)  %>%  formatPercentage('B', 2) %>%
  formatRound('A',digits = 0)
```

I know i can use scales

```
library(scales)    
comma_format()(1000000)
```

but I'm not sure how to combine that with DataTables

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Had this same issue:

Try This:

```
require(DT)
require(dplyr)

df1 = data.frame(A=c(1000000.51,5000.33, 2500, 251), B=c(0.565,0.794, .685, .456))

df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(A=round(A,digits=0))

datatable(df1)  %>%  formatPercentage('B', 2) %>%
  formatCurrency('A',currency = "", interval = 3, mark = ",")
```

[image]

Comment: If you use  '  as mark, you have to escape it: ` mark = "\\'" `.

Comment: I am seeing the decimal places in the A column using the solution above. I guess the `digits` option was supposed to fix this, but it appears not to anymore. See my alternate below.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `formatC`

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(A = formatC(round(A), format = "f", big.mark = ",", drop0trailing = TRUE),
         B = paste0(formatC(100 * B, format = "f", digits = 2), "%")) %>%
  datatable()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: the problem is that A and B are now character values and are no longer sorted numerically. Is there a datatable solution to this that retains their numerical value?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if `formatRound()` was created after this question was asked and answered, but here's a solution without using `formatCurrency()` (which seems a little hackish):

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

df1 = data.frame(A=c(1000000.51,5000.33, 2500, 251), B=c(0.565,0.794, .685, .456))

datatable(df1) %>%
  formatPercentage('B', digits = 2) %>%
  formatRound('A', digits = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer above for me showed the decimal places.

[image]

I was able to use a `digits` option within `formatCurrency()` and it worked:

```
df1 = data.frame(A=c(1000000.51,5000.33, 2500, 251), B=c(0.565,0.794, .685, .456))
datatable(df1)  %>%  formatPercentage('B', 2) %>%
    formatCurrency('A',currency = "", interval = 3, mark = ",", digits=0)
```

[image]