# Rounding currency formatted numbers in DT

Tags: r, formatting, dt

I'm trying to get the numbers in a currency format and then round them but I get unexpected behaviour from `DT` (v 0.1).

I want the values looking like `808084.227872401` into `£808,084.2`

Here's the code:

```
library(DT)

m <- structure(list(A = c(808084.227872401, 1968554.9592654, 751271.053745238, 
-248530.769710688, 1022891.09543523, -407303.626363765), B = c(143073.342325492, 
-1440469.87343229, -590080.736184761, -608299.78907882, 1167155.65688074, 
803870.898483576), C = c(-447086.9382469, 606572.488852836, 89371.3745637198, 
-1496047.6143101, -410103.544644035, 1106358.3287006), D = c(0.754009573487565, 
0.364774209912866, 0.525769896339625, 0.44853704655543, 0.909551323624328, 
0.439131782157347), E = c(98.8604132297185, 98.9055931760521, 
99.3795062166865, 98.5895350315005, 101.194549174315, 102.325111315431
)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

According to [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) this should work:

```
datatable(m) %>% formatCurrency("A", "£", digits = 1)
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in formatCurrency(., "A", "£", digits = 1) : 
>    unused argument (digits = 1)

Then I tried another command:

```
datatable(m) %>% formatCurrency("A", "£") %>% formatRound("A", 1)
```

But it only formatted the currency without rounding it.

[image]

Any ideas?

PS. I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242011/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-in-datatable-r) answer, but I don't want to display strings because I want to sort the numbers when displayed with `datatable`.

Comment: Why not use regular `round` first on that column and then feed to `datatable`?

Comment: I don't want to change the underlying data but only the way it's displayed. Plus I'd like to know what's going on when I use DT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My conclusion is that you cannot add 2 formatters to the same column with `DT`, although of course I could be wrong.

Note that, even this is not explicitly stated in the documentation of `DT`, only one formatter can be added per column table. Note also that on the examples in the link you provide, or when you type `?formatCurrency`, when they include two pipes `%>%`, they always affect to two different columns.

In your example, when you do

```
datatable(m) %>% formatRound("A", digits=1) %>% formatCurrency("A", currency="£")
```

the result is round for 1 digit with no currency, and if you do

```
datatable(m) %>% formatCurrency("A", currency="£") %>% formatRound("A", digits=1)
```

the result is the currency added with no rounding.

My knowledge on how R integrates with js is very limited, but looking at the R sources for [the package in cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DT/index.html), it looks like every format command in the pipe appends a formatter, but for some reason only one formatter comes into play:

```
formatCurrency = function(table, columns, currency = '$', interval = 3, mark = ',') {
  formatColumns(table, columns, tplCurrency, currency, interval, mark)
}

formatRound = function(table, columns, digits = 2) {
  formatColumns(table, columns, tplRound, digits)
}

formatColumns = function(table, columns, template, ...) {
  ...
  x$options$rowCallback = appendFormatter(
    x$options$rowCallback, columns, colnames, rownames, template, ...
  )
  ...
}

appendFormatter = function(js, name, names, rownames = TRUE, template, ...) {
  ...
  JS(append(
    js, after = 1,
    template(i, ...)
  ))
}
```

where every formatter ends up calling `formatColumns` with a different `template`, and `i` resolves an id for the column. As I said, I have no idea if this is because the append operations overwrites the formatter, or if it has to do with the execution.

---

*EDIT*: Sorry I accidentally pressed the post button and got interruped. I actually implemented a formatter that takes more arguments. The solution is a bit convoluted but it works. This is a formatter that accepts both currency and digits:

```
tplRound2 = function(cols, currency, digits) {
  sprintf(
    "var d = parseFloat(data[%d]); $(this.api().cell(row, %s).node()).html(isNaN(d) ? '' : '%s' + d.toFixed(%d).toString());",
    cols, cols, currency, digits
  )
}
```

You need to add all these functions to your session:

```
formatRound2 = function(table, columns, currency, digits = 2) {
  formatColumns2(table, columns, tplRound2, currency, digits)
}

formatColumns2 = function(table, columns, template, ...) {
  if (inherits(columns, 'formula')) columns = all.vars(columns)
  x = table$x
  colnames = base::attr(x, 'colnames', exact = TRUE)
  rownames = base::attr(x, 'rownames', exact = TRUE)
  x$options$rowCallback = appendFormatter2(
    x$options$rowCallback, columns, colnames, rownames, template, ...
  )
  table$x = x
  table
}

name2int = function(name, names) {
  if (is.numeric(name)) {
    return(if (all(name > 0)) name else seq_along(names)[name])
  }
  names = setNames(seq_along(names), names)
  unname(names[name])
}

appendFormatter2 = function(js, name, names, rownames = TRUE, template, ...) {
  js = if (length(js) == 0) c('function(row, data) {', '}') else {
    unlist(strsplit(as.character(js), '\n'))
  }
  i = name2int(name, names)
  if (is.character(name) || (is.numeric(name) && !rownames)) i = i - 1
  if (any(is.na(i))) stop(
    'You specified the columns: ', paste(name, collapse = ', '), ', ',
    'but the column names of the data are ', paste(names, collapse = ', ')
  )
  JS(append(
    js, after = 1,
    template(i, ...)
  ))
}
```

And then you can run with the new formatter to get the desired result:

```
datatable(m) %>% formatRound2("A", "£", digits=1)
```

(However this does not add the `,` every 3 digits, if you really need it I could add it to the formatter...)

---

*EDIT2 after comments*:

This would be the formatter function for using both currency and number of digits, plus the ',' marks:

```
tplRound3 = function(cols, currency, digits, interval, mark) {
  sprintf(
    "var d = parseFloat(data[%d]); $(this.api().cell(row, %s).node()).html(isNaN(d) ? '' : '%s' + d.toFixed(%d).toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{%d})+(?!\\d))/g, '%s'));",
    cols, cols, currency, digits, interval, mark
  )
}


formatRound3 = function(table, columns, currency, digits = 2, interval=3, mark=',') {
  formatColumns2(table, columns, tplRound3, currency, digits, interval, mark)
}
```

In order to use it just type

```
datatable(m) %>% formatRound3("A", "£", digits=1)
```

Comment: Sorry @epo3, accidentally pressed the "post" button, edited the post with a kind of complex solution.

Comment: Great answer. It would be great if you could add a comma every 3 digits. That would make the function complete. I guess you could suggest an improvement to `DT`. It would be a very useful function to add to the package.

Comment: You're more than welcome. I've updated the answer with the formatter including comma every 3 digits. Yes maybe I'll do a PR to `DT`. Thanks.

Comment: @lrnzcig nice answer! Any thoughts on how to display the a shortened abbreviation of the scale as "£13.4 k" or "-£98.5 mil" or "£53.5 bil"  or "-£42.2 mil"  or  simply "-£7.43" whilst still allowing numerical sorting in DT?

Comment: Just... great answer.

Answer (score 3):

After some research i figured that there is way to accomplish this within `formatCurrency()`

Changing the code to below will solve the issue:

> `datatable(m) %>% formatCurrency("A", '\U20AC', digits = 1)`