# Add commas to every number in shiny renderDataTable

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I would like to display large numbers with comma separation in a datable.  How would I include the format currency clause in the renderDataTable function in a Shiny app  in order to do this?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242011/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-in-datatable-r) post shows how to do add it to a regular DT, but I'm feeding the datatable into the UI.  I don't see currency as one of the [options](https://datatables.net/reference/option/).

```
output$dummy_data_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    data.frame(A=c(1000000.51,5000.33, 2500, 251), B=c(0.565,0.794, .685, .456)),
    extensions = 'Buttons',
    server=FALSE,
    options = list(
      pageLength = 50,
      scrollX=TRUE,
      dom = 'T<"clear">lBfrtip',
    )  # close options
  ) # close renderDataTable
```

Comment: The post you shared answers your question. You'll use `formatCurreny()`. Why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: Because you can't pipe a shiny render function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add comma to numbers every three digits in datatable (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242011/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-in-datatable-r)

Comment: you don't need to pipe the render function...just use `DT::datatable` and apply `formatCurrency` for that inside your render function.

Comment: Shree, please write how you would include the formatCurrency in my example above.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comments -

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput("dummy_data_table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$dummy_data_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
      data.frame(A=c(1000000.51,5000.33, 2500, 251), B=c(0.565,0.794, .685, .456)) %>%
        datatable(extensions = 'Buttons',
          options = list(
            pageLength = 50,
            scrollX=TRUE,
            dom = 'T<"clear">lBfrtip'
          )
        ) %>%
        formatCurrency(1:2, currency = "", interval = 3, mark = ",")
    ) # close renderDataTable
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed post.  Your example obviously works.  If I substitute this into my actual app, with the formatCurrency (and preceding pipe) commented out, the table renders.  However, when I insert it back in, the headings render, but there's a 'Processing' message on the screen in the background.  Any thoughts?

Comment: to add more color, that 'Processing' message just hangs